# Ruby, Candy and SQL-like mongo stuff

Tags: ruby, mongodb

So [Candy](http://github.com/SFEley/candy) is a really simple library for interacting with Mongo in Ruby.

My poor SQL brain is having a tough time figuring out how I should map out this problem:

There are `user`s, there are `thing`s. Each `thing` was made by one `user`, but should be accessible to a subset of all `user`s (specified within the `thing`). Leaving the specification of `user` out of the way for now, how would I get a list of all `thing`s that `user` **X** has access to?

```
class Thing
  include Candy::Piece
end

class Things
  include Candy::Collection
  collects :thing
end
```

Should I assign the allowed `user`s to a `thing` like this? (lets just use strings to reference `user`s for now)

```
t = Thing.new
t.allowed = ['X','Y','Z']
```

This seems about right to me, which would make me want to do:

```
Things.find(allowed:'X')
```

but it's not quite working…

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘call’ for {:allowed=>"X"}:Hash
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really sorry I took so long to catch this and respond.  This might be too late for your purposes, but:

Candy doesn't implement a `find` method. This is on purpose: if an object represents a collection, every access is implicitly *finding* something in that collection.  It's the same reason there is no `save` method. If the mapping is truly transparent, verbs that mean "Do this in the database" shouldn't be necessary.

So to do what you want, you could either just make a new Things object with the scope passed on creation:

```
x_is_allowed = Things.new(allowed: 'X')
```

...or you could save a step and do it by class method:

```
x_is_allowed = Things.allowed('X')
```

...or you could start with the whole collection and limit it by attribute later:

```
things = Things.new
x_is_allowed = things.allowed('X')
```

So...  Um.  All of those will work.  *But.* I have to warn you that I'm really not happy with the general usability of Candy right now, and of collections and array fields in particular. The biggest problem is accessors: the `[]` method isn't working like you'd expect, so you end up having to call `to_a` and `refresh` and other things that feel sticky and unpleasant.

This needs to be fixed, and I will do so as soon as I finish the driver rewrite (a related project called [Crunch](http://github.com/sfeley/crunch)).  In the short term, Candy is probably best viewed as an experiment for the adventurous, and I can't guarantee it'll save time until the interface is locked down a bit better. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: No problem at all! I've been on holiday so it's barely been any time at all for me :P This sounds fantastic - I'm investigating using Candy for a reasonably big (personal) project, I know it's a bad idea to consider Candy given your warning about the impermanence of it's API but it's so tasty! I'll certainly be using it for the testing phase, as the DB interaction is minimal and Candy is whole lines simpler! Let me know if there's any way I can help with it's development. Thanks candy, thandy.